# Swift3 : Hide UITableView if Empty

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10

I have a tableview, which I use as a part of the screen.

`@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!`

Sometimes I have data, and sometimes I don't.
I want to display the table only when data is present and hide it when there is no data.

I tried adding a constraint of height with lesser or equal to options. But if I do that, tableview is hidden even when I have data

what should I do?

I googled around and didn't find a solution, so asking here.

Disclaimer: I am new to iOS/Swift development. Sorry if this is already answered

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can show hide `tableView` like below.

You can check the count using the array with which you might be populating the data Or with the `tableView` property `numberOfRowsInSection`.

when there is no data

```
tableView.ishidden = true
```

when there is data

```
tableView.ishidden = false
```

Or you can use the delegate method as below.

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if array.isEmpty {
            self.tableView.isHidden = true
        }
        else {
            self.tableView.isHidden = false
        }
    }
```

More better way would be using didSet.

```
var dataArray: [String] = [] {
   didSet {
      if dataArray.count > 0 {
         //Update Table Data
      } else {
         //Hide Table and show so info of no data
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I didn't down vote but your suggestion to hide the table inside the `numberOfRowsInSection` delegate method is a bad suggestion. The view should be hidden long before any delegate methods are called.

Comment: @rmaddy Updated answer

Comment: Even OP can check array value before reload tableView. If `array.count ==0 ` then hide the tableView otherwise show tableView.

Comment: is: "tableView.isHidden = true" not "tableView.ishidden = true" .   "h"<>"H". Just for the first post. later the in override func viewWillAppear is ok.

Answer (score 5):

You can also try this, so that you can make use of the empty table space.

- Set outlet to your table height constraint and add the below line

  ```
  tableHeightConstraint.constant = array.count != 0 ? 250 : 0
  ```

[image]          [image]

Comment: Although this works, I am more inclined to set isHidden to true

Comment: Hmm that's okay. :)

Comment: this was useful for me because the isHidden variable was being tightly controlled by something else. In fact, with this, we can control the size of the table depending on the number of elements in the table. very useful for my Autocomplete application, and much more. we can hide row by row, and show row by row, making the table height extremely adaptive. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Set `tableView.isHiden = true` if no data to present.